# SPSS: Crosstabs multiple comparison

Tags: spss, chi-squared-test, multiple-comparisons

I have a table with 11 columns and 2 rows. Column 1 is the control group and I want to compare all the other columns with it. I'm not interested in comparing columns 2 - 11 with each other and I'm concerned that Bonferroni's correction (which seems to be the only option available) is overcompensating by multiplying the p value by 55 or however many comparisons it is. Is there something analogous to Dunnett's so that I can compare just with the control group? Or should I just do 10 chi-squared tests and multiply each p value by 10?

Also, when I do use Bonferroni's in a chi-squared, is it possible to see the exact p values?

Comment: You are right with your grievance, but it is not Bonferroni correction's problem; it is SPSS options problem. Unfortunately, SPSS doesn't allow to specify user-defined number of comparisons by hand, e.g. via syntax. So, you should just produce the table with uncorrected p-values and then multiply it according to the number of comparisons you actually imply.

Comment: @ttnphns, I think that's the correct answer, why not make it official?

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to display the (corrected or otherwise) p values for multiple comparisons or will a series of 2x2 tables do the trick? I'm assuming I'm right that Bonferroni is as simple as multiplying the p value by the number of comparisons made?

Comment: @Matthew, the Bonferroni correction is not equivalent to multiplying the observed p-value by the number of comparisons. That would quickly lead to adjusted p-values >1, which is non-sensical. Instead, you *divide* alpha (typically .05) by the number of comparisons. Eg, if you want to adjust for 5 comparisons, you would use .05/5 = .01 as your new threshold for 'significance'.

Comment: I'm with you. Altman, in his textbook, seems to multiply by n comparisons. With this particular table, the uncorrected p values were either way above anything anyone would consider significant (and so not worth correcting anyway) or extremely small (and so multiplying by 10 rendered something apparently sensible)--hence why it seemed to make sense. Is there a good text on multiple comparisons?

Comment: @Matthew, I largely don't know of any such books. There is [Multiple Comparisons using R](http://www.amazon.com/Multiple-Comparisons-Using-Frank-Bretz/dp/1584885742), which is short, clear & applied, but it is entirely R focused, since you use SPSS it may not help much. You could search Amazon--there must be some--but I couldn't give a recommendation. This is a subject that is typically covered well enough in experimental design books, though.